# div classes and CSS rows

Tags: html, css

If I have say 6 items within a div and I want to space 3 then 3 directly underneath can I use one div to contain my 6 total divs and space them to wrap under or do I need to have two separate divs to contain 3 in each?

I have tried to use a div to separate at 3 boxes in each div but I cannot get the boxes to line up.

What I am attempting to do is this-

```
 box       Box      Box

 box       Box      Box
```

currently it looks like this

```
box box box box box box
```

If I

```css
.boxes {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box4">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box5">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box6">Box 6</div>
</div>
```

split the div class=boxes at 3 and create another for the last three boxes it will split into two rows, but I cannot get them to line up. is there a way to wrap around from the code I have written?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) if you want to set the number of desired columns.

```css
.boxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box4">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box5">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box6">Box 6</div>
</div>
```

If you prefer you can also use the CSS `repeat()` function:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

Comment: instead of `1fr 1fr 1fr` you can also use `repeat(3, 1fr)` - it's easier to change that `3` in one place, or pass it as a variable than having to add another rule when the necessity comes to wrap them as `1` `2` `4` etc...